# Understanding the trace operator and non-diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where  $B$ is a diagonal matrix with $b > 0$ along the diagonal.

Then we have $$tr(AB) = tr(BA) = b* tr(A),$$
where we can factor out $b$ from the trace operator.

Now suppose  $B$ is no longer a diagonal matrix. Suppose it has $b > 0$ along the diagonal and $b' \in \mathbb{R}$ in the off-diagonals.

If we're interested in computing $tr(AB)$, is it still possible to still factor out some function of $b$ from the trace operator?

Here's a simple example I tried:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 9 \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}b & b' \\ b' & b\end{bmatrix}$

then we have
\begin{align}
tr(BA) &= tr\left(\begin{bmatrix}b & b' \\ b' & b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 9 \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= tr\left(\begin{bmatrix}b + 3b' & 2b + 9b' \\ 3b + b' & 9b + 2b'\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= 10b + 5b'
\end{align}

\begin{align}
tr(A) &= tr\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 9 \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= 10
\end{align}

So it looks like $$tr(AB) = b * tr(A) + (a_{12} + a_{21}) * b'$$

where $a_{12}, a_{21}$ are the off-diagonal entries in $A$.

Comment: I'm not having pen and paper to think of it right now, so not very sure. Did you try some examples _i.e._ by taking two matrices as you indicated, and checking if the claim is true?

Comment: I tried one simple example, and it seems to work. However, I'm not 100% clear on it. I'll add it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. For any four numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$, you have$$\operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b&b'\\b'&b\end{bmatrix}\right)=b\operatorname{tr}\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{bmatrix}+b'(z+y).$$

Answer (score 0):

If $B_{ij} = \begin{cases} b:& i=j \\b':& i\neq j \end{cases}$ then $B=(b-b')I + b'{\bf 1}{\bf 1}^T$. Plugging this back in gives

$$
\operatorname{tr}(AB)
=(b-b')\cdot \operatorname{tr}(A) + b'\cdot\operatorname{tr}(A{\bf 1}{\bf 1}^T)  
= (b-b')\cdot \operatorname{tr}(A) +b'\cdot{\bf 1}^T A {\bf 1}
$$